# Bootstrap rails drop down navbar stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navbar

The collapsed navbar for mobile versions will not open. The website is www.insaka.org. This is the navbar code. I could have sworn it was working last time I checked it, but now it is not. Any ideas?

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation_links' %>
    <% render 'layouts/nav_links_for_auth' %>
    </ul>


      <div>
           <a href="http://www.insaka.org/pages/candidates" class="button2">Donate</a>
           </div>
      <div>
          <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto img-responsive max-width:25px height:auto" src="../images/blue insaka logo.jpg">
      </div>


  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? also can you show gemfile and application.js file. I may have come across this issue before with Rails 5 and Bootstrap 4

Comment: 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'

Comment: I'd probably start with updating the bootstrap to the 4.1v which is the official release. Some of the classes are now deprecated so it might be an issue with that.

Comment: Make sure you include the appropriate files in your app.js file. And make sure you’ve included the jquery-rails gem.

Comment: Gemfile- ruby '2.4.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

Comment: gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'devise'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'jquery-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end

Comment: group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
end

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me add more code to the section above unless I wrote more about it

Comment: This is our application.js file-  
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs

rearrange the require tree like this and remove popper from the gemfile and/or require tree. It should work now for Bootstrap 4Alpha but i'd really just update the Bootstrap gem to the new bootstrap. Try the rearranging of the tree first tho.

Comment: Also remove rails-ujs and put bootstrap_ujs instead.

Comment: We got it figured out. Thank you Pablo and Bradley

Answer (score 0):

If you check for javascript errors in the console you will find the problems:

- popper.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- holder.min.js

These three js files could not be found.

[image]